# How to keep track of the memory usage in C?

Tags: c, memory-management

I have to do a project in C where I have to constantly allocate memory for big data structures and then free it. Does there exista a library with a function that helps to keep track of the memory usage so I can be sure if I am doing things correctly? (I'm new to C)

For example, a function that returns:
A) The total of memory used by the program at the moment, OR
B) The total of memory left,
would do the job. I already googled for that and searched in other answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [tcmalloc](http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/): you are looking for a heap profiler, although [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) might be more useful initially.

Answer (score 3):

Although some people excoriate it, the book ["Writing Solid Code"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556155514) by Steve Maguire has a lot of reasonable ideas about how to track your memory usage without modifying the system memory allocation functions.  Basically, instead of calling the raw `malloc()` etc functions directly, you call your own memory allocation API built on top of the standard one.  Your API can track allocations and frees, detect double frees, frees of non-allocated memory, unreleased (leaked) memory, complete dumps of what is allocated, etc.  You either need to crib the code from the book or write your own equivalent code.  One interesting problem is providing a stack trace for each allocation; there isn't a standard way to determine the call stack.  (The book is a bit dated now; it was written just a few years after the C89 standard was published and does not exploit `const` qualifiers.)

Some will argue that these services can be provided by the system `malloc()`; indeed, they can, and these days often are.  You should look carefully at the manual provided for your version of `malloc()`, and decide whether it provides enough for you.  If not, then the wrapper API mechanism is reasonable.  Note that using your own API means you track what you explicitly allocate, while leaving library functions not written to use your API using the system services - as, indeed, does your code, under the covers.

You should also look into [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/).  It does a superb job tracking memory abuses, and in particular will report leaked memory (memory that was allocated but not freed).  It also spots when you read or write outside the bounds of an allocated space, spotting buffer overflows.

Nevertheless, ultimately, you need to be disciplined in the way you write your code, ensuring that every time you allocate memory, you know when it will be released.

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried about memory leaks, valgrind is probably what you need. On the other hand, if you're more concerned just with whether you're data structures are using excessive memory, you might just use the common `mallinfo` function included as an extension to `malloc` in many unix standard libraries including glibc on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you allocate/free memory, you could log how big your data structure is.